# Connectig to jira application server via browser remotely

Tags: windows, jira, system-administration, windows-firewall

I've installed Jira application server Version 7.1.4 on windows 10, I can connect to it with VM Ubuntu at my pc and also I can connect to it locally but I can't connect to it in other pc's in our office network.
I Use telnet MyserverIp and Myserver port and everything was ok.
let me know what is your idea.

Update: I changed firewall to turn off but it doesn't matter.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added tomcat8w.exe to "Allow a program or feature through windows firewall" at control panel windows firewall and problem is resolved.